# jQuery clone() fields not going through

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, clone

I have a form on my page which gives the user the possibility to add new fields on demand. I use the jQuery `clone()` method to achieve that, here's the snippet I'm using:

```
//  Dynamic forms
$('.addField').bind('click', function() {
    var tmp = '#' + $(this).attr('parent') + ' tr td div.clonedInput';  //  get the path to elements
    var x = $(this).attr('parent').split('_'); //   get the element's identifier
    var ident = '#' + x[0];

    var num = $(tmp).length;    //  count elements  
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);   //  increase the number of the new element

    //  Create the new element and manipulate its id
    tmp = x[0] + '_' + newNum;
    var newElem = $(ident + '_' + num).clone().attr('id', tmp);

    //  Manipulate the new element's children
    newElem.find('input, select, textarea, label').each(function() {
        var kid = $(this);
        var y = '';
        var z;

        y = kid.attr(kid.attr('for') == undefined ? 'name' : 'for').split(x[0] + '_' + num);
        z = tmp + y[1];
        if (kid.attr('for') == undefined) {
            kid.attr('name', z);
            kid.attr('id', z);
            if (kid[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea') {
                kid.html('');
            } else {
                kid.attr('value', '');
            }
        } else {
            kid.attr('for', z);
        }
    });

    //  Add the new element after the last one
    $(ident + '_' + num).after(newElem);

    //  Enable the associated "Remove" button
    $('.remField[parent="' + $(this).attr('parent') + '"]').attr('disabled', '');
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the dynamically added fields are not included in the results of form submission. I tried this snippet:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

and the fields are not shown in the resulting string.

What is wrong with the code?

**EDIT:**
Original HTML

```
<h1>Add a recipe</h1>
<form name="add-recipe" action="add-recipe/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="formname" value="add-recipe" />
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Basic details</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Recipe name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_name" id="name" maxlength="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="img">Recipe image:</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="rec_img" id="img" /></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><label for="cat">Category:</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="rec_cat" id="cat">
                    <option value="-1"> ( Select a category ) </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="desc">Recipe description:</label></td>
            <td class="center"><textarea maxlength="1024" name="rec_desc" id="desc" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Times and servings</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="prep">Preparation time:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_prep" id="prep" maxlength="5" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><label for="cook">Cooking time:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_cook" id="cook" maxlength="5" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><label for="serving_size">Serving size:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_serving_size" id="serving_size" maxlength="45" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><label for="servings_per_recipe">Servings per recipe:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_servings_per_recipe" id="servings_per_recipe" maxlength="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Ingredients</span></td>
        </tr>
        <!--    INGREDIENTS     -->
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table class="subform" id="ing_container">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="clonedInput" id="ing_1">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="ing_1_ing">Ingredient:</label><br />
                                    <select name="ing_1_ing" id="ing_1_ing">
                                        <option value="-1"> ( Select an ingredient ) </option>                  
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="ing_1_amount">Amount:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="ing_1_amount" id="ing_1_amount" maxlength="5" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="ing_1_det">Details:</label></br />
                                    <textarea maxlength="255" name="ing_1_det" id="ing_1_det" cols="56" rows="8"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="ing_1_meas">Measurement:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="ing_1_meas" id="ing_1_meas" maxlength="45" />
                                </div>                          
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center">
                <input type="button" class="addField" parent="ing_container" value="Add ingredient" />&nbsp;<input type="button" disabled="disabled" parent="ing_container" class="remField" value="Remove ingredient" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--    STEPS   -->
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Steps</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table class="subform" id="step_container">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="clonedInput" id="step_1">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="step_1_desc">Description:</label></br />
                                    <textarea maxlength="1024" name="step_1_desc" id="step_1_desc" cols="56" rows="8"></textarea>
                                </div>                      
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center">
                <input type="button" class="addField" parent="step_container" value="Add step" />&nbsp;<input type="button" disabled="disabled" parent="step_container" class="remField" value="Remove step" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Nutrition facts</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center"><input type="submit" value="Proceed" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure the new form elements reside between the `<form></form>` tags?

Comment: Post this as an answer, please. I haven't checked that.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the original HTML code, especially since you seem to be employing some unusual tricks (like a nonstandard `parent` attribute) which might be breaking things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the new form elements reside between the `<form></form>` tags? Use the DOM inspector in Chrome or IE or Firebug for Firefox to make sure.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, mblase75! I wouldn't have even looked at that.

Comment: I came across this response and it led to me finding that I needed to change where I opened my form.  Thanks!